# SQL Server: Syntax near keyword 'CREATE' when batch executing CREATE SCHEMA and CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql-server, syntax, jdbc, batch-file

I'm trying to set up an SQL Server 2008 database using JDBC (latest version).
I have a list of setup sql commands which I'd like to execute all together:

Basically what I do is:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch("CREATE SCHEMA test")
stmt.addBatch("CREATE TABLE test.a (x integer)")
stmt.executeBatch();
```

this throws:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
```

If I execute those commands separately, they work as expected. Would I need to add a commit here (like stmt.addBatch("COMMIT")? I'm not running a transaction, so this shouldn't be necessary.

Also this is not an error saying test schema does not exists -- it's a syntax error and this puzzles me.

The docs only provide DML commands as an example to addBatch, but i believe batch is not limited to DML only.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

m.

Comment: see if you can run those commands in SSMS without a GO command between them.

Comment: Contrary to what Mikael Eriksson says, create schema needs to be in its own batch.  You're executing it with other stuff in the same batch, hence the error.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid SQL

```
CREATE SCHEMA test
CREATE TABLE test.a (x integer)
```

This is valid

```
CREATE SCHEMA test
GO
CREATE TABLE test.a (x integer)
```

This is not valid

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;
CREATE TABLE test.a (x integer);
```

Error is

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'create'.
```

The reason is that `create schema` must be in it's own batch (Thank you Ben for pointing that out). `GO` is a batch separator so that is ok. `;` is a statement separator within a batch and that is not ok. The first code is valid because the `create table` statement(s) is part of the `create schema` statement. They run in the same transaction as one statement.

My guess is that `addBatch` appends a `;` at the end of each statement. Do only one call to `addBatch` with the entire `create schema` statement including `create table`.